# How to open zipped csv file using namelist() and for loop?

Tags: python, csv, zip

The file structure I am working with is essentially a zip file with a folder and then 2 folders labeled X and Y which contain two csvs. The `namelist()` returns the two csv files I am deciding between. I have constructed the csv file name as `csvName` but am getting confused on how to open the csv. My code is below.

```
listofFiles = zipDataFile.namelist()
if (subwindow.X == '1' and subwindow.Y != '1'): #determines X or Y folder
    for file in listofFiles:
        if (file.endswith('X/'+csvName)):
            with open(file) as csvfile:
                *rest of code*
```

Comment: I'd expect you'd need to call something on the zipfile to open the data inside of the zip. The bare `open` call you're using won't do that.

Comment: Use `zipDataFile.open(file)`.